# How to receive value as each separate object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to receive value as separate object array for each element.

**This is my code**

```
 <input class="name" name="name[]" type="text" />
 <input class="date_of_birth" name="DoB[]" type="text" />
 <input class="age" type="radio" name="age" value="1" />
 <input class="age" type="radio" name="age" value="0" />
    var kidName = [];
    $(".name").each(function() {
        kidName.push($(this).val());
    });

    var newDob = [];
    $(".date_of_birth").each(function() {
        newDob.push($(this).val());
    });
    var age = [];
    $(".age:checked").each(function() {
        age.push($(this).val());
    });
    var kids = {
        "kidName": kidName,
        "newDob": newDob,
        "age": age
    };
```

**How i get the value with this as separate array for each element.**

```
kids: {
    kidName: ["Test1", "Test2"]
    newDob:  ["20/02/2000", "20/03/2018"]
    age:  ["19", "1"]
}
```

**But i want to receive these values like this**

```
kids:
{
   kidName: ["Test1"],
   newDob:  ["20/02/2000"],
   age:  ["19"]
},
{
   kidName: ["Test2"],
   newDob:  ["20/03/2018"],
   age:  ["1"]
}
```

How can i achieve this, what changes should i make to receive values like this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Have you taught about using Object prototype? as in the "Kid" would be an object then you can push new kid to the array of kids.

Comment: Why do you need arrays in the second case?

Comment: The arrays are totally useless.

Comment: And how did you possibly get `19` from `class="age"` radio inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to put the form group into a container. Select the container and use [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to loop thru the containers. In this example, the container is a `div` with class `input-group`

Note: you need to change the name of radio button every container.

```js
var result = $(".input-group").map(function() {
  return {
    kidName: $(this).find('.name').val(),
    newDob: $(this).find('.date_of_birth').val(),
    age: $(this).find('.age:checked').val(),
  }
}).get();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="name" name="name[]" type="text" value="Test1" />
  <input class="date_of_birth" name="DoB[]" type="text" value="20/02/2000" />
  <input class="age" type="radio" name="age01[]" value="1" checked/>
  <input class="age" type="radio" name="age01[]" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="name" name="name[]" type="text" value="Test2" />
  <input class="date_of_birth" name="DoB[]" type="text" value="20/03/2018" />
  <input class="age" type="radio" name="age02[]" value="1" />
  <input class="age" type="radio" name="age02[]" value="0" checked/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is present in your question, the best I can suggest is just to reformat the data you have into the format you need.

Id you're able to provide your html, it may be possible to get the data into this format initially rather than reparsing it.

```js
const kids = {
  kidName: ["Test1", "Test2"],
  newDob:  ["20/02/2000", "20/03/2018"],
  age:  ["19", "1"],
};

const kidsArraysToObjects = kids => kids.kidName.map(
  (_, i) => Object.keys(kids).reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr]: kids[curr][i]
  }), {})
)

const result = kidsArraysToObjects(kids)

console.dir(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have tried

```
var kids = []


$(".name").each(function(index, value) {
    if (kids[index] == undefined) {
        kids[index] = {}
    }
    kids[index].kidName = $(this).val()
});

$(".date_of_birth").each(function(index, value) {
    if (kids[index] == undefined) {
        kids[index] = obj
    }
    kids[index].newDob = $(this).val()
});

$(".age:checked").each(function(index, value) {
    if (kids[index] == undefined) {
        kids[index] = obj
    }
    kids[index].age = $(this).val()
});
```

NOTE: I haven't tested this

Answer (score 0):

try this replace `parent-selector-each-record` with common class or id of each row
by using this approach you get exact data. also you can use @OliverRadini approach

```
 var kids = [];
            $("parent-selector-each-record").each(function() {
                var kid = {};
            kid["kidName"] = $(this).find(".name").val()
            kid["newDob"] = $(this).find(".date_of_birth").val()
            kid["age"] = $(this).find(".age:checked").val()
            kids.push(kid);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to reformat your object structure after that you get the data, since it will avoid some coupling with your HTML. In other words, it avoids to touch your JavaScript when you want to change your HTML.

```js
const kids = {
    kidName: ["Test1", "Test2"],
    newDob:  ["20/02/2000", "20/03/2018"],
    age:  ["19", "1"]
}
const keys = Object.keys(kids);
const result = kids[keys[0]].map((_, i) => { 
    return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = kids[key][i];
        return obj;
    }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```